# Prepare for segue error in lldb

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

I'm calling it like this

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if (segue.identifier == "hat") {
        let itemVC: ItemViewController = sender.destinationViewController as ItemViewController
        itemVC.myDelegate = self
        itemVC.nameArray = self.nameArray
    }
}
```

but the lldb freezes up once I call to go to the next view controller. Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
segue.destinationViewController
```

instead of:

```
sender.destinationViewController
```

Comment: simple fix. Can't believe I over looked that.